# MySQL TABLE_ROWS estimate

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if MySQL's `TABLE_ROWS` estimate of total number of rows in a table has any bounds on how muhc it is off or guaranteed range of error?

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like the numbers `SHOW TABLE STATUS` emits, it's off by at least +/- 40% and is sometimes off by several orders of magnitude.

The only way to know for sure how many rows are in a table is `COUNT(*)`, or if there are no deleted rows or other forms of holes in your numbers and your `AUTO_INCREMENT` value started at 1, then the `MAX(id)` might be accurate enough.

Comment: `MAX(id)` can be different than the number of rows in the table for a variety of reasons, not only deleted rows.

Comment: You might have holes introduced by aborted transactions, it's true, but I'm just presenting it as an option that applies if certain conditions are met.